# Code for reading values from ML8511 and MQ131 sensors

Tags: pi-3, gpio, sensor

I'm looking for a way/libraries to read the values from the ML8511 and MQ131 sensors with a MCP3008 ADC on Raspberry Pi 3B using Python.